# Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp, jstl

Estoy desarrollando un aplicativo web en NetBeans y me está generando este error cuando ingreso al index. Y no sé que está pasando.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:344)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:153)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: allí dice que no tienes una clase para [tag:jstl] que forma parte del api de [tag:servlets], ambas cosas son parte de Java EE, si usas maven probablemente debas marcarlas como provided ya que en muchos servidores de aplicaciones vienen ya incluidas por defecto

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví descargando el siguiente jar y agregandolo al proyecto en la carpeta WEB-INF/lib.

[jstl-1.2.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar)

Y leyendo mas, también se daba la solución descargando y agregando este jar también.

[jsp-api-2.0.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp-api/2.0/jsp-api-2.0.jar)